# Change user icons on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop-icons

How can I change user icons of regular user icons (Downloads, Documents, Photos, Videos, Music,...)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change the icon reference by editing the hidden desktop.ini file under each shell folder.

**Desktop.ini**

To edit the desktop.ini file for the `Downloads` folder, press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `notepad %userprofile%\downloads\desktop.ini`. Change the icon reference from:

```
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-184
```

to

```
IconResource=D:\Websites\Media\myicon.ico,0
```

Similarly do this for other shell folders.

**Registry**

Other areas in Explorer use the icon settings from the registry. To change that, in the Registry Editor (`Regedit.exe`), go to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID
```

Create the {GUID} applicable to a shell folder, and create a `DefaultIcon` key underneath. For example, to customize Downloads folder icon, you create this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{088E3905-0323-4B02-9826-5D99428E115F}\DefaultIcon
```

Then double-click `(default)` and set its value data to a .ico file. A sample REG file:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID{088E3905-0323-4B02-9826-5D99428E115F}\DefaultIcon]
>
> @="D:\Websites\Media\myicon.ico,0"

Repeat this for each shell folder icon you want to customize, and the [other GUID strings](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-quick-access-other-shell-folders-file-explorer/) are as follows:

Src: [Remove Quick access, Folders (6) and Other Shell Folders from File Explorer?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-quick-access-other-shell-folders-file-explorer/)

```
{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}  Desktop

{D3162B92-9365-467A-956B-92703ACA08AF}  Documents

{3DFDF296-DBEC-4FB4-81D1-6A3438BCF4DE}  Music

{24AD3AD4-A569-4530-98E1-AB02F9417AA8}  Pictures

{F86FA3AB-70D2-4FC7-9C99-FCBF05467F3A}  Videos
```

Logoff and login back after editing the registry and/or desktop.ini.